# Group by a second parameter

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT c.user1, c.user2, a.username AS author_name, SUBSTRING(m.content,1,20) as content, m.viewed, m.sent_date, m.author, c1.username AS username1, c2.username AS username2  
FROM conversation c
INNER JOIN message m ON m.conversationid = c.conversationid
INNER JOIN user c1 ON c1.userid = c.user1
INNER JOIN user c2 oN c2.userid = c.user2
INNER JOIN user a ON a.userid = m.author
WHERE (c.user1 = 33 OR c.user2 = 34)
GROUP BY c.conversationid ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC
```

This groups by the conversationid. When it groups by and keeps one row, I need it to be the row with the most recent sent_date.

Is this possible with this structure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safe way to do this is to add a subquery to calculate the most recent sent date for each conversation:

```
SELECT c.user1, c.user2, a.username AS author_name, SUBSTRING(m.content,1,20) as content, m.viewed, m.sent_date, m.author, c1.username AS username1, c2.username AS username2  
FROM conversation c
INNER JOIN message m ON m.conversationid = c.conversationid
inner join (select conversationid, max(sent_date) as maxsentdate from message group by conversationid) mc on m.conversationid = mc.conversationid and m.sent_date = mc.maxsentdate
INNER JOIN user c1 ON c1.userid = c.user1
INNER JOIN user c2 oN c2.userid = c.user2
INNER JOIN user a ON a.userid = m.author
WHERE (c.user1 = 33 OR c.user2 = 34)
GROUP BY c.conversationid ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC
```

What this is doing is calculating the maximum sent date for each message.  It then joins this to the message table, which gets you the last message.  You could, in theory, get duplicates, if two messages were sent at exactly the same time.  I think that is unlikely.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do this is so that I get the most recent author, not sent date. Can you adjust the line of extra code for that?

Comment: @Luke . . . The author is on the message.  So, getting the most recent message should be getting you the most recent author.

Comment: This works! Thanks. Could you explain to me how that piece of SQL is working? I can't understand why it works!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are grouping by only one column in the `SELECT` list. MySQL uses an extension to the `GROUP BY` clause that allows columns in the SELECT list to be excluded from being named in a group by or aggregate function. This can lead to unexpected results. (see [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html))

From the MySQL Docs:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. ... You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Ideally you will use a subquery to get the result. This subquery will get the max sent_Date for each conversation and then you will join that back to your messages table to return the remaining columns needed:

```
SELECT c.user1, 
  c.user2, 
  a.username AS author_name, 
  SUBSTRING(m.content,1,20) as content, 
  m.viewed, 
  m.sent_date, 
  m.author, 
  c1.username AS username1, 
  c2.username AS username2  
FROM conversation c
INNER JOIN message m
  ON m.conversationid = c.conversationid
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(sent_date) sent_date, conversationid
  from message
  group by conversationid
) m1
  ON m1.conversationid = c.conversationid
  AND m.sent_date = m1.sent_date
INNER JOIN user c1 
  ON c1.userid = c.user1
INNER JOIN user c2 
  ON c2.userid = c.user2
INNER JOIN user a 
  ON a.userid = m.author
WHERE (c.user1 = 33 OR c.user2 = 34)
ORDER BY m.sent_date DESC
```